# Pull selected files to VPS repository

Tags: git

I have a remote repository at bitbucket, and two local repositories (localhost and VPS) of the same project.
I have been making changes to my localhost repository and pushed to remote repository.

```
$ sudo git push -u origin --all
```

These changes are made in a new branch, and they are not merged with master branch.
Now I want to pull two files (the ones I've changed) into VPS repository.
How can I do it?

Comment: Do you really need `sudo` to push?

Comment: I think it is because I first did: "$ sudo git init", but not sure.

Comment: You could do a `sudo chown -R <user> *` and never care about sudo again.

Comment: After that, I've tried again and get:"fatal: Unable to create '/home/manolo/MiServer/itransformer-2.0/.git/index.lock': Permission denied"

Comment: Seems like you have forgot that `-R` which makes `chown` work recursively. If you didnt forget that...hmmm...maybe `chmod 755 -R *`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the VPS repo:

```
git pull
git checkout <feature_branch> <file> <file2>
```

That will get the specified files into whatever branch you are currently on. Just commit them if you want.

ALTERNATIVELY

Just check out the feature branch:

```
git pull
git checkout <feature_branch>
```

Comment: Should I merge my changes to master branch before?

Comment: That's what I would do: merge to master, push to remote repo, pull from VPS. Is it right?

Comment: No, you dont need to merge to master. Just push the feature branch (as you already did according to your question containing `--all`) and fetch it on the VPS.

Comment: After this I can't get my web page: 503 Service Unavailable

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch your branch changes on the VPS repository, just do:

```
$ git fetch
$ git checkout -b your_branch origin/your_branch
```

The files should be there